# Importar una key de azure KeyVault a Databricks

Tags: azure

Estoy trabajando en Databricks, el objetivo es importar/mandar llamar una llave/clave que se encuentra almacenada en AzureKeyVault, En Databricks se ha intentado importar la llave de la misma manera a como se importa un secret, mencionar que lo que se requiere  importar/mandar llamar no es un secret sino una llave.

Hay una forma de importar la llave como tal, lo que se tiene que importar es la llave que se encuentra dentro de Claves en el KeyVault.

Comparto el codigo para importar como si fuese un secret:

```
secrets_Scope = "nombre_del_ambiente"
secrets_name = "nombre_de_la_llave"
dbutils.secrets.get(scope= secrets_Scope, key= secrets_name)
```

Ademas comparto el formato que tiene la llave almacenada en azure keyVault:

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----

jnh2kTXk2cfvHprvT+RrkfHf7Er/KSj7W8pr/LUQTSIGdJhbFkDVEk/+ac1kCAwEAAQ==.........

-----END PUBLIC KEY-----